# Closing IME onEditorAction

Tags: android

Hey all , first post on Stack so be patient.

I am trying to close the IME after user presses enter in EditText.

I've tried using `android:imeOptions="actionDone"/"actionNext"` in the layout.xml

I've set up setOnEditorActionListener on said EditText and am looking for code to signal IME it's done.

tnx.

Answer (score 6):

This works just fine

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```